# Windows Phone Grid zIndex

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, canvas, grid, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on an application where I have a grid of buttons (can be various number of them). Atm I'm using a 4x4 Grid to place them and stretch them to size. The issue is that these buttons can be dragged around, and they should be hovering **over** the rest of the buttons while they are dragged. They can be also clicked, in which case they slowly hover over to another point on the screen.

The problem arises from the fact that Grid doesn't handle zIndex, and putting a canvas under the Grid wouldn't help. I'm not sure if having a canvas with absolute coordinates would work on different sized screens, and the buttons are also supposed to hover over other elements outside the grid as well (and the grid is in a pivot - the button has to hover over whatever is outside the pivot as well).

The question is if there is any way other than a canvas with zIndex, and if not, how can I achieve a proper Grid-like layout with a canvas.

UPDATE:

I'm using the following code to move the button:

```
    private TranslateTransform dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
        private void Button_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragTranslation.X + dragTranslation.Y > 100)
        {
            //ClickLock to avoid the tap event from firing
            clickLock = true;
        }
        draggedButton.RenderTransform = dragTranslation;
        dragTranslation.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        dragTranslation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    }
```

Note that I've skipped parts such as reassigning `dragTranslation` in the ManipulationStarted event.

Comment: Hi Dracor - I can't figure out exactly what you're doing here.  I set a grid on top of a canvas and had a button underneath the grid - none of it is draggable.  Can you explain the scenario a little more?

Comment: I'll update the question in a sec.